# Permutations of word MANIFOLD

Tags: permutations

In how many ways can the letters of the word MANIFOLD be arranged so that the vowels are separated?

I tried total permutations in which vowels are together, which gives 36000 which was wrong.

Comment: You consistently ask low quality questions. See the [help centre](https://math.stackexchange.com/help) for tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All letters are distinct, so there are $8!$ permutations. This count both good and bad ones.

Consider two of the vowels as one letter ($3!/1!$ cases). Each of the cases constitutes $7!$ bad permutations.

Consider three vowels as on letter ($3!$ cases). Each of the cases constitute $6!$ bad permutations which were however counted twice by the $3! 7!$ above, so these bust be added.

I.e. $8!-3!7!+3!6!$

Comment: @GirishArora I get 14400, what do you think is the answer?!

Comment: 8! - (3!7! + 3!6!) Does not sums up to 14400...however (8! -3!7!) + 3!6! = 14400 which is correct. I used BODMAS before.

Comment: @GirishArora BODMAS is really BO(DM)(AS) (assuming "O" has something to do with exponents), where the two pairs in brackets have equal priority. In the case of DM, it is ambiguous, and in the case of AS, it goes left-to-right.

Comment: @arthur thanks for reminding me that

Comment: @pritt balagopal i mentioned in the comment that answer is right